# How to know when we popback to one through navigation flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

Hi i m navigating from page 1 to page 2 in flutter.my question is when i navigated from page 1 to page 2 using:

```
Navigator.push()
```

Now i wanna pop back from page 2 to page one i want to know that how can i know from page 1 that i popback from page 2
Using:

```
Navigator.pop()
```

Simply i wanna update page 1 when i pop back from page to but i dont know how to get to know that i navigated from page 2.

I have a bloc that blongs to page 1 and i want to call a event when i popback from page 2 without passing page 1 bloc to page 2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Navigator.pop() method accepts an optional second argument called result. There is an example in the documentation https://flutter.dev/docs/cookbook/navigation/returning-data for returning data from a second screen to a first screen. This can be adapted to trigger an action on the pop result. Something like, on the first screen:

```
fun(BuildContext context) async {
    final result = await Navigator.push(context,ROUTE);
    if (result == 'Returned') {
        do something...
    }
}
```

and on the second screen:

```
Navigator.pop(context, 'Returned');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this in your **Page 1**

```
Navigator.of(context).push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Page2(),)).whenComplete(() {
   // Navigation pushed back
   // Do what you want here
});
```

Comment: But he wants to pop the context!

Comment: OP said `Simply i wanna update page 1 when i pop back from page to but i dont know how to get to know that i navigated from page 2.`